# Group by list multiple columns with conditions

Tags: python, pandas

Having

|  | car_id | speed | section |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 10 | a |
| 1 | 1 | 10 | b |
| 2 | 1 | 30 | c |
| 3 | 1 | 10 | d |
| 4 | 2 | 10 | e |
| 5 | 2 | 0 | f |
| 6 | 2 | 10 | g |
| 7 | 3 | 0 | h |

I want a concatenated string in two columns, one containing the sections if speed <=10 (legal_speed) and the others (illegal_speed). The values with speed 0  should be an empty string:

|  | car_id | legal_speed | illegal_speed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | a, b, d | c |
| 1 | 2 | e, g |  |
| 2 | 3 |  |  |

I have been trying

```
df.groupby('car_id').agg(list)
```

but not quiet there yet

Comment: For `car_id` 2 `legal_speed` should be `e, g`, right?

Comment: @Ch3steR sorry you are right, editing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Categorize the column `speed` into `legal` and `illegal` labels, then group the dataframe by `car_id` and labels and aggregate `section` using `join`:

```
s = pd.cut(df['speed'], [0, 10, np.inf], labels=['legal', 'illegal'])
df.groupby(['car_id', s])['section'].agg(', '.join).unstack()
```

Result

```
speed     legal illegal
car_id                 
1       a, b, d       c
2          e, g     NaN
3           NaN     NaN
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution that utilizes `np.select` and `pivot`:

```
df['x'] = np.select([df['speed'] > 10, df['speed'] == 0], ['illegal_speed', 'na'], default='legal_speed')
new_df = df.pivot(values='section', columns='x').groupby(df['car_id']).apply(lambda g: g.apply(lambda col: col.dropna().tolist()).str.join(', ')).reset_index().rename_axis(None, axis=1)
```

Output:

```
>>> new_df
   car_id illegal_speed legal_speed na
0       1             c     a, b, d   
1       2                      e, g  f
2       3                            h
```

Here's another variant, which is more elegant although a bit longer:

```
df['x'] = np.select([df['speed'] > 10, df['speed'] == 0], ['illegal_speed', 'na'], default='legal_speed')
new_df = df.groupby('car_id').apply(lambda g: g.groupby('x')['section'].agg(list).str.join(', ')).unstack().fillna('').reset_index().rename_axis(None, axis=1)
```